# narrow down instanceof to a specific subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

how do one narrow down `instanceof` to a specific child without ending up with the parent class .

for example if i should have a parent class `StackoverflowUsers` then i have direct subclass of `TenKUsers`,`HundredKusers` etc etc.. Now my question is how do i use `instanceof` to get if an `Object` is an instance of one of the direct subclasses of `StackoverflowUsers` and not end up with the option of that my `object` is an instance of `StackoverflowUsers` .. is that possible?

Comment: what about HundredKusers.class.isAssignableFrom() ?

Comment: i tried that too, was very helpful thank you @Vyncent ,but is that a better approach or an alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `instanceof TenKUsers` (etc.) idiom.

It will tell you if the object you are looking at is the child of that base class.

Since you imply `TenKUsers` is a child of `StackoverflowUsers`, `instanceof StackoverflowUsers` will **also** be `true` for that object, of course.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you've saved me. last question, but is `HundredKusers.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())` an alternative to this or ? just asking but i have upvoted and will accept

Comment: @supporter you're welcome. The reflection method `isAssignableFrom` is documented as follows: "Answers true if the type represented by the argument can be converted via an identity conversion or a widening reference conversion (i.e. if either the receiver or the argument represent primitive types, only the identity conversion applies).". So it does a little more (see the primitive part for instance) but should be equivalent. Typically one would favor `instanceof` over reflection if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the superclass itself with checking `.getClass()`, but "grandchildren" will also be matched...

You could use reflection, but in general reflection should be avoided (is kind of "cheating").

```
public class T {

    static class StackoverflowUsers {}

    static class TenKUsers extends StackoverflowUsers {}
    static class HundredKusers extends StackoverflowUsers {}

    static class EtcEtc extends TenKUsers {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Instance of String: "+checkInstance(new String()));
        System.out.println("Instance of StackoverflowUsers (superclass): "+checkInstance(new StackoverflowUsers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of TenKUsers (direct subclass): "+checkInstance(new TenKUsers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of HundredKusers (direct subclass): "+checkInstance(new HundredKusers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of EtcEtc (indirect subclass): "+checkInstance(new EtcEtc()));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("using reflection:");
        System.out.println("Instance of String: "+checkInstanceUsingReflection(new String()));
        System.out.println("Instance of StackoverflowUsers (superclass): "+checkInstanceUsingReflection(new StackoverflowUsers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of TenKUsers (direct subclass): "+checkInstanceUsingReflection(new TenKUsers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of HundredKusers (direct subclass): "+checkInstanceUsingReflection(new HundredKusers()));
        System.out.println("Instance of EtcEtc (indirect subclass): "+checkInstanceUsingReflection(new EtcEtc()));

    }

    private static boolean checkInstance(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof StackoverflowUsers) && (o.getClass() != StackoverflowUsers.class);
    }

    private static boolean checkInstanceUsingReflection(Object o) {
        Class<?> superclass = o.getClass().getSuperclass();
        return superclass == StackoverflowUsers.class;
    }
}
```

which returns:

```
Instance of String: false
Instance of StackoverflowUsers (superclass): false
Instance of TenKUsers (direct subclass): true
Instance of HundredKusers (direct subclass): true
Instance of EtcEtc (indirect subclass): true

using reflection:
Instance of String: false
Instance of StackoverflowUsers (superclass): false
Instance of TenKUsers (direct subclass): true
Instance of HundredKusers (direct subclass): true
Instance of EtcEtc (indirect subclass): false
```

Maybe you should rethink your classes. It seems like `TenKUsers` could also be a boolean flag stored inside of StackoverflowUsers. Or even better: give your StackoverflowUsers an `EnumSet<Archievments>` and make Archievments contain "TenKUser" and "HundredKusers".

Comment: thank you sir, you also helped me understand it. i will upvote

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Mena, if you want to use `instanceof` to check, you can make your superclass `Stackoverflowusers` abstract to ensure no instances can exist and then check with:

```
object instanceof Stackoverflowusers
```